# sidebar icon descriptions - pops up to early

Tags: javascript, html, css

I struggling to find a proper way to animate CSS display property. The attached example contains a simple function which shrinks the whole sidebar. A click of the arrow executes this behavior. The problem is, as soon as the sidebar expands again the description behind each icon appears below the icon first and slides into the correct position afterwards. It is propably because of missing space but how can I avoid that, since CSS animation of the property is not possible?

```js
     $(".sidebar ul li").on("click", function() {
            $(".sidebar ul li.active").removeClass("active")
            $(this).addClass("active")
        })

        $("#switch").on("click", function() {
            $(".header-box span").toggleClass("fs-5")
            $(".sidebar ul li span").toggleClass("hide")
            $("ul").toggleClass("fs-4")
            $(".sidebar").toggleClass("shrink")
            
        })
```

```css
    body {
    background: #eee;
}

#side_nav {
    background: #242424;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#side_nav.shrink {
    min-width: 72px;
    max-width: 72px;
}

.content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

hr {
    height: 3px;
}

hr.h-color {
    background: #eee;
}

.sidebar li.active {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0px -5px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.sidebar li.active a,
.sidebar li.active a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.sidebar li a {
    color: #fff;
}

.sidebar ul li span.hide {
  display:none
}

ul {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.header-box span {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <!-- benötigte meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>StackOverflow</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- FONT Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-container d-flex">
        <div class="sidebar" id="side_nav">
            <div class="header-box px-2 pt-3 pb-4">
                <h1 class="fs-3">
                    <span class="bg-white text-dark rounded shadow d-block py-2 me-2 w-100 text-center">SO</span>
                </h1>
                
                <button class="btn d-block close-btn px-1 py-0 text-white" id="switch"><i class="fa-solid fa-left-long"></i></button>
            
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-5 fs-6">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>General</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>Something</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>Even longer Text</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My attempt was to create a span element into each li and simply toggle those span elements. I guess its a quick and dirty attempt but it fails during my animation problem, as the attribute display cant be animated. I tried to avoid it with setting a delay but it seems not to work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just added a simple css here it's looks smoother than the previous solution, but not perfect.

the css I added is :

```
.sidebar .list-unstyled li {
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The above code will give a fixed height to the li element. And will hide the overflow content.

And removed this css :

```
.sidebar ul li span.hide {
  display:none;
 }
```

```js
$(".sidebar ul li").on("click", function() {
            $(".sidebar ul li.active").removeClass("active")
            $(this).addClass("active")
        })

        $("#switch").on("click", function() {
            $(".header-box span").toggleClass("fs-5")
            $(".sidebar ul li span").toggleClass("hide")
            $("ul").toggleClass("fs-4")
            $(".sidebar").toggleClass("shrink")
            
        })
```

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
}

#side_nav {
    background: #242424;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#side_nav.shrink {
    min-width: 72px;
    max-width: 72px;
}

.content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

hr {
    height: 3px;
}

hr.h-color {
    background: #eee;
}

.sidebar li.active {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), inset 0px -5px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.sidebar li.active a,
.sidebar li.active a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.sidebar li a {
    color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .list-unstyled li {
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

ul {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.header-box span {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <!-- benötigte meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>StackOverflow</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- FONT Awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-container d-flex">
        <div class="sidebar" id="side_nav">
            <div class="header-box px-2 pt-3 pb-4">
                <h1 class="fs-3">
                    <span class="bg-white text-dark rounded shadow d-block py-2 me-2 w-100 text-center">SO</span>
                </h1>
                
                <button class="btn d-block close-btn px-1 py-0 text-white" id="switch"><i class="fa-solid fa-left-long"></i></button>
            
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-5 fs-6">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>General</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>Something</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none px-3 py-2 d-block"><i class="fa-solid fa-house pe-3"></i><span>Even longer Text</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The text seems fine but if you perform the action in full page, you will notice the icons are out of position if shrinked.

Comment: It's because  you have this code in js "$("ul").toggleClass("fs-4")"  which is making its shape bigger and smaller.